# Channel single connection(Session) yo eventhandler mapping

Tags: netty, channel, event-loop

We are newbies to Netty and trying to use it as a client.Our use case is to spawn multiple worker threads but to send requests on the same channel(single TCP connection).

But from what we understand  each of Netty's channels are tied to an eventloop which are tied to threads.

Please help to answer if Netty allows a single channel to be reused by multiple eventloops.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same `Channel` from different `Thread`s but all it's IO / `ChannelPipeline` operations will be done by the `EventLoop` which uses the same `Thread` and will never change.

Comment: Thanks for your response.Does it mean if there are 100 requests to be sent to a server(non-netty) over a single channel(connection), it would be using the singlei/o thread(eventloop) and will be processed sequentially.